# CorePlot - Scatter Plot issue using the Custom Labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-plot

Im trying to draw a scatter plot and after exploring a while got the axis labels right. I'm using the label policy as none and added my own custom labels. But for some reason it just draws a straight line, even though I have used the sample data differently. Here's the pic of the graph from the simulator

http://tinypic.com/r/farkvb/8

And the code I'm using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


[super viewDidLoad];
self.sortedYAxisArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];


// All intervals taken from Google
NSDate *yesterday = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -86400.0];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yy"];
self.startDate = [formatter stringFromDate:yesterday];
self.endDate = [formatter stringFromDate:today];
self.yAxisLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1.23234",@"1.23456",@"1.23231",@"1.23453",@"1.23239",@"1.23459",@"1.23233",@"1.23456",@"1.23234",@"1.23456",@"1.23234",@"1.23456",@"1.23234",@"1.23456",@"1.23234",@"1.23456",@"1.23234",@"1.23456",@"1.23234",@"1.23456",@"1.23234",@"1.23456",@"1.22212",@"1.21223", nil];

[self.sortedYAxisArray addObjectsFromArray:self.yAxisLabels];
[self.sortedYAxisArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
self.yMinValue = [[self.sortedYAxisArray firstObject]doubleValue];
self.yMaxValue = [[self.sortedYAxisArray lastObject]doubleValue];
NSLog(@"first object >> %@ last Object >> %@",[self.sortedYAxisArray firstObject],[self.sortedYAxisArray lastObject]);
NSLog(@"min and max values >>> %f %f",self.yMinValue,self.yMaxValue);

[self configureHost];
[self configureGraph];
[self configureAxis];
[self configurePlot];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

 - (void)configureHost {

self.chartingView.alpha = 0.02;

UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];
UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
visualEffectView.frame = self.chartingView.frame;
[self.view addSubview:visualEffectView];
self.hostView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.chartingView.frame];
[self.view addSubview:self.hostView];




    }
    - (void)configureGraph {

CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: self.hostView.bounds];
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 60.0f;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 40.0f;
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
graph.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
NSTimeInterval xLow       = 0.0;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xLow) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(24.0)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(self.yMinValue) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(self.yMaxValue - self.yMinValue)];
self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;


  }
  - (void)configureAxis {

    // NSDate *refDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:31556926 * 10];

CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:36/255.0f green:44/255.0f blue:89/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
axisTextStyle.fontName  = @"Helvetica-Bold";
axisTextStyle.fontSize  =  12.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor darkGrayColor];
majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.2f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
minorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];
minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.3f;

// 2 - Get axis set
   CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;

axisSet.yAxis.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
axisSet.xAxis.tickDirection = CPTSignNone;
axisSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;

//Configuring X-axis
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay/6);
x.majorTickLength = 3.0f;
x.minorTickLength = 1.0f;
x.minorTickLineStyle = tickLineStyle;
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 5.0f;
x.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
x.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;
x.labelOffset = 15.0f;
NSArray *customTickLocations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:6],
                                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:12],
                                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:18],
                                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:23],
                                 nil];
NSMutableArray *minorCustomTickLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i =0 ; i <24 ; i++) {
    [minorCustomTickLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:i]];

}
NSArray *customXAxisLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.startDate,@"6 AM",@"12 PM",@"6 PM",self.endDate, nil];
NSUInteger labelLocation = 0;
NSMutableArray *customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[customXAxisLabels count]];
for (NSNumber *tickLocation in customTickLocations) {
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: [customXAxisLabels objectAtIndex:labelLocation++] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
    newLabel.offset = axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset + axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength;
    [customLabels addObject:newLabel];

}
x.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
x.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:customTickLocations];
x.minorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:minorCustomTickLocations];

//Configuring Y-axis
CPTXYAxis *y=axisSet.yAxis;
//y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(-0.5);
y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(5.0f);
y.majorTickLength = 3.0f;
y.minorTickLength = 1.0f;
y.minorTickLineStyle = tickLineStyle;
y.minorTicksPerInterval = 5.0f;
y.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
y.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;
y.labelOffset = 3.0f;


NSMutableArray *customYAxisLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.yAxisLabels count]];
NSMutableArray *customYTickLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for(int i =0; i<5;i++) {

    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",(self.yMinValue + i*(self.yMaxValue - self.yMinValue))]  textStyle:axisSet.yAxis.labelTextStyle];
    NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromFloat(self.yMinValue + i*(self.yMaxValue - self.yMinValue));
    newLabel.tickLocation = location;
    newLabel.offset = axisSet.yAxis.labelOffset + axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength;
    [customYAxisLabels addObject:newLabel];
    [customYTickLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];

}
y.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customYAxisLabels];
y.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:customYTickLocations];



}
- (void)configurePlot {

CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"Data Source Plot";

CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;


CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
NSTimeInterval xLow       = 0.0;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xLow) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(24.0)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(self.yMinValue) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(self.yMaxValue - self.yMinValue)];

CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
lineStyle.lineWidth              = 2.0;
lineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:36/255.0f green:44/255.0f blue:89/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;





// Add plot symbols
CPTMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
symbolLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol plotSymbol];
plotSymbol.fill               = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor]];
plotSymbol.lineStyle          = symbolLineStyle;
plotSymbol.size               = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);
dataSourceLinePlot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;

[graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

 }

  #pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods
 -(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
return [self.yAxisLabels count];
 }

  -(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
NSInteger valueCount = [self.yAxisLabels count];
switch (fieldEnum) {
    case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
        if (index < valueCount) {
            return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
        }
        break;

    case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Data Source Plot"] == YES) {
            NSLog(@"y-axis label value >> %@",[self.yAxisLabels objectAtIndex:index]);
            return [self.yAxisLabels objectAtIndex:index];
        }
        break;
}
return [NSDecimalNumber zero];
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The horizontal gridlines, tick marks, and labels are at the locations given in the `customTickLocations` array (0, 6, 12, 18, and 23). The y-value of the plot points matches the axis label text. Since those values only vary by 0.00001 from one point to the next, you can't see a difference on a scale of 0 to 30.

Comment: How should I change the y axis scale then ?  I solved it by  returning index instead of y-axis value in plot data source but I'm not sure if it,s the right way

Comment: Please correct me if im wrong .. So , if i'm receiving the data from the back-end , i should first calculate the minimum and maximum y -axis values and then set the plot space range accordingly ..something like this ? plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(yminvalue) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(ymaximum - yminimum value)];

Comment: @Rango Yes, that's a good way to calculate the plot range. When setting up the axis labels, be sure to set the `tickLocation` of each label to a value matching its label (or use a different labeling policy and let the `labelFormatter` create the label text from the tick location).

Comment: I have changed the y-axis labels as you have said but still the desired result hasnt come .. i believe im doing something wrong with the x-axis labels .. My requirement is to show the date labels exactly as written in the code.. Can you please let me know how to use the dateformatter to plot the x-range corresponding to the date value.. I have added the edited version of code ..

Comment: The x-axis isn't visible because it crosses the y-axis at y=0. Either set the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` to make it cross inside the `yRange` or use the `axisConstraints` to hold it in a particular place. The y-axis labels would be much simpler if you stick with the default fixed interval labeling policy and set a `labelFormatter` to format the label text. Set the `majorIntervalLength` to control the distance between adjacent major tick marks and labels. The axis will automatically set the major and minor tick locations and create axis labels for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric ..I have finished 90% of graph.. I have couple of questions though .. In the data sets i receive from the back-end , i get 0's for few intervals where there is no data .. how can i show the graph as blank in those intervals .. For example if i get the data set for the first 12 hours as "0.0" and for the next 12 hours , i get the proper data..i want to show a blank graph (be it for candlestick or line chart) for those initial hours.. how do i achieve that ?

Comment: Got It Eric .. Im returning the zeroes as NAN values .. thanks a lot for all the help..